# What is Hungarian Notation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hungarian-notation

Does it have any use cases in native Javascript, Jquery, or Angular? I found out about this notation when I was reading about the use of $ in front of variable names. The $ is used a lot in Jquery, does it have any relation to Hungarian Notation also?

Comment: Were you unable to use google when you wrote this question?

Comment: have you tried any simple internet searching?

Comment: In a way, yes. It's an indicator that the variable contains a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

> What is Hungarian Notation?

[The StackOverflow tag itself](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hungarian-notation/info) says: "Hungarian notation is a language-independent naming convention in which an identifier's prefix indicates its type. Examples include iCustomerId, sFirstName, etc."

> Does it have any use cases in native Javascript, Jquery, or Angular?

It can have, if you want it to.

> The $ is used a lot in Jquery, does it have any relation to Hungarian Notation also?

As Felix King said: "In a way, yes. It's an indicator that the variable contains a jQuery object."

---

Again, more thorough answers to all those questions are available on the internet, it's not a SO question.